# Stuck message in HornetQ

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I have a queue which contains a large number of unacknowledged messages, which are also increasing significantly. Any help how to investigate futher or any ideas how to check which are those messages.

Sample data from JBoss admin console

```
Message Count           8,605
Scheduled Message Count 0
Consumer Count          15  
Delivering Count        8,605
Messages Added          3,792,745
```

Other Information
JBoss vesrion : JBoss-6.1.0.Final GA Edition

I have tried PrintData class to print details of messages, but it only gives me message ids, It would be helpful if someone can suggest how to get message data

Comment: You can use QueueBrowser JMS API to get content of message.

Comment: @Varsha Can I use QueueBrowser to check data from remote server

Comment: Yes. You just need to pass IP of server while creating connection and make sure JNDI port is accessible. Else you can use JMS monitoring tools like HermesJMS.

Comment: @Varsha, I managed to create a Pojo to use Queue Browser. but it is only reading if any message is not picked up by consumer, and not reading the stuck messages.

Comment: There is no API to read messages which are in delivering state. You can try with setting consumer-window-size to 0, which means no consumer buffering.

Comment: Thanks @Varsha, I read some other blogs also where I am getting two suggestion, One is that one of the consumer is slow which can be resolved by setting buffer window to zero, other is sudden increase in load. I am working on both to get more info